# Consequences of the degree conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions, selberg-class

the title is quite explicit: I would like to know the consequences of the degree conjecture for the Selberg class.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shoot, I thought the title meant the degree conjecture for modular parametrizations (and thus the ABC conjecture). :-P

Comment: @Sylvain: it's not strictly necessary, but for instance I am a working number theorist who has no idea what the degree conjecture for the Selberg class might be.  Perhaps you could include a reference so that I and people like me can follow along?

Comment: Of course. See the following link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class
The degree conjecture simply states that for all $F$ in the Selberg class, $d_{F}$ is a non negative integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are no direct consequences of the conjecture, but it seems like the natural first step in solving the bigger orthonormality conjecture (and/or related issues like unique factorization) which in turn imply a major open problems in number theory, the Artin conjecture (Dedekind conjecture, in the case of unique factorization).

You can find a proof of both implications in:

- M. Ram Murty, [Selberg's Conjectures and Artin L-functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9407219) (1994)

And more information on the relationship between degrees and orthonormality in Kaczorowski and Perelli's series of articles on the Selberg class.